# Resource files or 'CreateWindow' function for GUIs?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

My program has a static interface, but I don't know what's the best way to make my interface. With resource files or with the `CreateWindow` function using the `WM_CREATE` message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Id recommend starting with dialog resources first. Then, if/when that is insufficient, make your own windows directly.

As a hardcore native developer, if you really want to make applications with a nice GUI, i hate to say this, but you'll get much more bang for your buck if you go with .NET's WPF - or even Windows Forms as a window layout language.

MS have made a concerted (and to my mind, somewhat malicious) effort to not add necessary new features for native applications so we are left building everything from scratch: the native controls don't support alpha aware painting, don't support back buffering, havn't been upgraded with the new Windows 7 widgets like ribbon bars, havn't been given any kind of animation system, and the dialog template based layout system is inflexible at best.

Comment: interesting. is there any way to use WPF in C/C++ without managed code? I hate using managed code in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but there is one problem. There only is a `DIALOG` statement and it uses dialog units for its width and height. I want to use pixel dimensions.

Comment: That is by design, and, frankly, better: DIALOG units automatically scale with the size of the system font - which users might change because they like a different size, or because they have a high DPI display.

Comment: @Jay.lee - no way to use WPF native code. Well, not without writing a lot of managed code with some kind of p/invoke layer. Seems a lot of effort tho.

Comment: According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/11/09/quick-tour-of-new-mfc-functionality.aspx the Ribbon interface is supported by the newer versions of MFC.

Comment: Ironically, the Windows team released a native API called the "Windows Ribbon Framework". The "ribbon interface" supported by MFC is a 3rd party library meaning you're not allowed to distribute apps developed with it without acquiring a license: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809